# Changing limit in y axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The y axis of my plot doesn’t reach 2.0 (*10^10), I want that tick mark to be displayed on the y axis as well. I have tried to change this in property inspector and through the code generation on the figure but have not been successful.

[image: Plot in matlab]

Comment: yes, you are a great person. thank you

Comment: I wouldn't say *great*. All I did was type [`[matlab] y axis limit`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+y+axis+limit) into the search bar at the top of this page.